# How To Update Google Maps SDK iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, cocoapods, ios11

I had been update Xcode , and while I'm running my app I'm getting this error message:

> Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication applicationState]
>   PID: 14616, TID: 312485, Thread name: com.google.Maps.LabelingBehavior, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 21

Searching online I found it's `SDK` bug of `Google Map` and I need to upgrade `SDK Google Maps` pod version, when I'm trying to upgrade the `Google Maps SDK` I got this message in terminal:

> [!] Failed to connect to GitHub to update the CocoaPods/Specs specs repo - Please check if you are offline, or that GitHub is down

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to refresh `cocoapod` repo.

```
$sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
$pod setup
```

Cocoapod Setup may take some times to done.

```
$pod install
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually i also get same when I updated my system and xcode.

I found that when system is update my cocoapods are automatically removed from the system, so i tried `sudo gem install cocoapods` which installed the cocoapod again in my system. Then I used `pod install` to update my pods.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @vahid's answer, what happened here is that your Specs repo has not been updated to the latest version.

A [Spec is a version descriptor for a specific Pod](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/specs-and-specs-repo.html). Your cocoapods installation maintains a local copy of the Specs repo to [relieve some workload off GitHub's servers](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5697#issuecomment-236604410).

Very old versions of cocoapods used to refresh the local Specs repo every `pod install`. Nowadays you need to specifically tell it to fetch the latest version.

@vahid's answer, while correct, is a bit unsafe and time-consuming for my taste.

The official docs [suggest](https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_repo_update) this method for manually fetching the latest Specs repo:

```
pod repo update
```

[This](https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_install) switch forces the previous command to run automatically prior to the Pod installation:

```
pod install --repo-update
```